# AWS Cli CURL with Header in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Apologies about this question but I'm running low on ideas about this.  We're creating a jenkins pipeline that uses SSM to download a few files to nodes.

The escaping on this seems almost impossible to work out.  Even SSM in the command shell is having issues:

```
header='Authorization: Bearer NjA5MDg4Mdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsddsfsr1223434'
```

Then the command:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids i-12344556677 --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters "commands=cd /tmp; wget -d --header=${header} https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt" --output text --query Command.CommandId --region eu-west-1
```

I've tried multiple \, different " ' in all sorts of places but I just cannot get it to work.

Example error:

```
    aws ssm send-command --instance-ids i-1232131212312 --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters 'commands=cd /tmp; wget -d --header='Authorization: Bearer NjA5M33333444444444444444U' https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt' --output text --query Command.CommandId --region eu-west-1
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: NjA5M33333444444444444444U https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt, Bearer
```

Has anyone here done this?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the error? Do you have some log? Could you use several lines instead only one?

Comment: The errors vary depending on format.  Even hardcoding the Bearer token can throw up something similar to the below.

`aws ssm send-command --instance-ids i-23423423b --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters 'commands=cd /tmp; wget -d --header=${header} https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt --output text --query Command.CommandId --region eu-west-1

Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input:
commands=cd /tmp; wget -d --header=${header} https://git.kpn.org/projects/CMS/repos/openteam-aws-ami-patching/raw/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are struggling with running commands due to hard core escaping requirements, you may want to consider creating a file that you can then dump using cat command:

```bash
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
   --instance-ids i-12344556677 \
   --parameters "commands=$(cat command.txt)" \
   --output text --query Command.CommandId --region eu-west-1
```

If you want a quick escaping fix, you can also try:

```bash
header='Authorization: Bearer NjA5MDg4Mdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsddsfsr1223434'
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids i-12344556677 \
   --document-name AWS-RunShellScript \
   --parameters "commands=['cd /tmp', 'wget -d --header=\'${header}\' https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt']" \
   --output text \
   --query Command.CommandId --region eu-west-1
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly this doesn't work.  It breaks with the following

`Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: '"' for input:
commands=cd /tmp; wget -d --header="'Authorization: Bearer NjA5MDg4Mdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsddsfsr1223434'" https://git.org/projects/files/raw/requirements.txt`

It puts the error points  ^ under r in requirements

Comment: @DaveShaw, you referring to `cat` or to the `escaping` try?

Comment: this was escaping.  I can try cat too :)

Comment: @DaveShaw, please try both of this (I updated the shell escape attempt) haha

Comment: Thanks, you set me on the right path.  The final working syntax was :

`aws ssm send-command --instance-ids -12344556677 \
  --document-name AWS-RunShellScript  \
   --parameters "commands=['cd /tmp', 'wget -d --header=\'${header}\' https://git.kpn.org/projects/CMS/repos/openteam-aws-ami-patching/raw/requirements.txt']" \
  --output text   \
  --query Command.CommandId   --region eu-west-1`

Now for Jenkins.....

Comment: Glad it helped @DaveShaw! So it needed a combination of the escape and bracket syntax haha

Comment: Yes it did, thanks.  Jenkins is being absolutely awful with the pipeline now.... another day wasted it seems.  This will be a new question if I can't figure it out.